# How not to execute JavaScript code when the screen has a specific size?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following to add and remove CSS classes based on the current scroll position:

```
$(function() {    
    var header = $(".grid-bar");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 400) {
            header.addClass("move");
         } else {
            header.removeClass("move");
        }
    });
});
```

But I want to disable the addition and removal of the CSS classes on a screen size smaller than 800px.

I have tried wrapping the code in a resize function but after I do so, it stops responding at all:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if ($(window).width() => 800){          

      var header = $(".grid-bar");
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scroll >= 400) {
                header.addClass("move");
             } else {
                header.removeClass("move");
            }
     });

  } 
});
```

Comment: The line should read `if ($(window).width() >= 800){`

Comment: Try a >= vs =>. => is an arrow function in JS.

Comment: @Crawdingle it didnt make any difference changing the arrow

Comment: CSS Media Query, only define the class when it is the correct size.....

Comment: You want that `if` test *inside* the "scroll" handler. Or just do it with a CSS media query.

Comment: Read the question again. The class also depends on the scroll position.

Comment: Cannot use media query because the class defines an animation and adds to an exsiting class

Comment: it could be useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

Comment: https://www.coalmarch.com/insights/how-to-execute-javascript-based-on-screen-size-using-jquery This could help you

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you have an improper operator for "greater than or equal to". The following is incorrect:

```
if ($(window).width() => 800) { 
//                    ^^ this operator is wrong

if ($(window).width() >= 800) { 
//                    ^^ it should be like this
```

Also, you need to bind and unbind the scroll handler whenever the screen size changes. You will need to keep track of whether or not the scroll handler is bound or not. Here is what that looks like:

```
const $window = $(window);
const $header = $(".grid-bar");
let isBound = false;
const scrollHandler = function() {
  const scroll = $window.scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 400) {
    header.addClass("move");
  } else {
    header.removeClass("move");
  }
}
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($window.width() >= 800) {
     if (!isBound) {       
       $window.on('scroll', scrollHandler);
       isBound = true;
     }
  } else if (isBound) {
    $window.off('scroll', scrollHandler);
    isBound = false;
  }
});

$window.trigger('resize');
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1mru359x/5/

Comment: Have you actually tried this code? I don't think this is going to work if `isBound` is a `const`.

Comment: @Ryan Wheale I tried your suggestion but it dont fire at all now

Comment: @Codi: Looking at the code, you have to resize the window first for the scroll event handler to get attached.

Comment: I updated the code and added a fiddle (sorry I hadn't tested). `isBound` should not have been a const, and you must manually trigger the initial resize event in order to get it to run the first time.